# Fiber bundle and fibration of classifying space

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

Let $BG$ is classifying space of $G$ topological group.

If $G$ is any compact group and $H$ is a closed subgroup of $G$, then the
inclusion map $i:H\rightarrow G$ induces 
\begin{equation*}
G/H\rightarrow BH\rightarrow BG
\end{equation*}
a fiber bundle?

If $G$ is any compact group and $H$ is a closed subgroup of $G$, then the
inclusion map $i:H\rightarrow G$ induces
\begin{equation*}
G/H\rightarrow BH\rightarrow BG
\end{equation*}
a fibration?

If $G$ is any compact group and $N$ is a closed normal subgroup of $G$, then
the quotient map $\pi :G\rightarrow G/N$ induces
\begin{equation*}
BN\rightarrow BG\rightarrow B\left( G/N\right) 
\end{equation*}
a fiber bundle?

If $G$ is any compact group and $H$ is a closed normal subgroup of $G$, then
the quotient map $\pi :G\rightarrow G/N$ induces 
\begin{equation*}
BN\rightarrow BG\rightarrow B\left( G/N\right) 
\end{equation*}
a fibration?

Comment: What is the difference between fiber bundle and fibration? $B$ is defined up to homotopy equivalence only, and, up to that, any map is a fibration.

Comment: Do you have arbitrary compact topological groups? Do you have compact Lie groups? Which kind of fibration do you ask for?

Comment: This question shows I definitely need some more hypothesis for parts of [this question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/235503/homotopy-fiber-of-a-map-between-classifying-spaces).

Comment: $G$ is any compact topological group. not Lie group

Comment: Why is this on hold? What is unclear? Is it just because M. Onat wrote "fibration" instead of "fiber sequence" (it's true, as @AlexDegtyarev pointed out, that you might as well assume that $BH \to BG$ is a fibration, but then the question is whether the homotopy fiber is equivalent to $G/H$)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this is not true for Q1 and Q2.

To be specific we probably need to pick a particular model for $BG$, and there are several. For the argument I will give, the following property is sufficient: there exist isomorphisms $\pi_{i+1}(BG) \cong \pi_i(G)$ of homotopy groups.

Let $G = S^1$ and let $H$ be the subgroup of torsion elements (the roots of unity). The group $G$ is abelian so $H$ is normal, and $H$ is totally disconnected so $\pi_0(H) \cong H$ as sets. Any open set in $G$ intersects any coset $gH$ nontrivially, so the quotient space $G/H$ has the indiscrete topology and its homotopy groups vanish.

If the answer to any of the first two questions that you asked was affirmative, there would be an exact sequence in homotopy groups of the form
$$
\cdots \to \pi_1(G/H) \to \pi_1(BH) \to \pi_1(BG) \to \cdots
$$
and this would be an exact sequence
$$
\cdots \to 0 \to H \to 0 \to \cdots
$$
which is not possible.

Comment: This nice example shows I definitely need more hypothesis for parts of [this question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/235503/homotopy-fiber-of-a-map-between-classifying-spaces). My guess is that $G \to G/H$ locally having a section is enough for Q2 here, do you think that's right?

Comment: Thanks Tyler Lawson. What do you think the last two question?

Comment: The Topology of Fiber Bundles Lecture Notes (Ralph L. Cohen) says that

Proposition 2.15: Let $p:EG\rightarrow BG$ be a universal principal $G$
-bundle and $H<G$. Then there is a fiber bundle $BH\rightarrow BG$ with
fiber the orbit space $G/H$.

Proof:
This bundle is given by $G/H\rightarrow EG\times _{G}G/H\rightarrow EG/G=BG$
together with the observation that $EG\times _{G}G/H=EG/H=BH.$

Comment: @M.Onat I haven't looked in your reference but I'll venture a guess that $H$ is supposed to be closed

Comment: I'm starting to think that $H$ closed may not be enough, @DenisNardin. Does that guarantee that $G \to G/H$ is a principal $H$-bundle, specifically, that it is locally trivial? I suspect that might be actually what you need for this.

Comment: @OmarAntolín-Camarena I'm not sure. I'm think that it might be enough if we assume that $G$ and $H$ are locally contractible, but I never think about these pathological cases

Comment: Keio Nagami says in his article (cross sections in locally compact groups, 1963) Theorem: Any closed subgroup of a locally compact, finite dimensional
group has a local cross section. Morever, the quotient map G-->G/H is an H-principal bundle if and only if it has a local section. So, my questions for compact groups G and closed subgroups H is true. İsn't it?

Comment: @Tyler Lawson You says that G/H has the indiscrete topology but it is not true. So, this example is not contradiction.

Comment: @M.Onat I am reasonably certain that $G/H$ has the indiscrete topology. Suppose you have a nonempty open subset of $G/H$. Then its preimage in $G$ is a nonempty open subset $U$ such that, for any $h \in H$, we have $h \cdot U = U$. Since $U$ is nonempty, it contains an interval $V$ between angles $\theta$ and $\theta + \epsilon$ for some $\epsilon > 0$. However, there is a root of unity $h$ of angle less than $\epsilon$, and so $U \supset \bigcup h^n \cdot V = S^1$.

Comment: However, if you have an argument that $G/H$ is not indiscrete, please let me know and we can try to figure out what the discrepancy is.

Comment: @Tyler Lawson Sorry. Thank you. I see. When i firstly asked the question, i didn't write $H$ is closed subgroup of $G$. Later, i edited this part. The example which you gave is true for before version. İ know that if $G$ is a Lie group and $H$ is a closed sobgroup of $G$ then Q1 is true. it is not closed $H$ which you gave. İsn't it?