# fibre sequence of classifying space

Tags: topological-groups, classifying-spaces, fibration

I read Steve Mitchell's *[Notes on principal bundles and classifying spaces](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Notes-on-principal-bundles-and-classifying-spaces-Mitchell/48d9f0f16900ea62773b4f86b761aca71906804b)* (pdf).
There is a theorem: Let $G$ be any topological group, $H$ an admissible
normal subgroup. Then there is a homotopy-fibre sequence $BH\overset{Bi}{\rightarrow }BG\overset{%
B\rho }{\rightarrow }B(G/H)$ where $i:H\rightarrow G$ is the inclusion and $%
\rho :G\rightarrow G/H$ is the quotient map.

I need a reference (an article or book, not lecture notes) for this theorem with ''admissible hypotesis''.

Comment: Have you seen this: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/235503/homotopy-fiber-of-a-map-between-classifying-spaces ?

Comment: I have seen but May's Classifying spaces and fibration is a reference for this theorem? I am not sure.

Comment: This is not really my area of expertise, so I can't judge. I thought this post was relevant.